# using Jquery.load() with javascript content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am trying to grab items, organized with Javascript, and put them on the content of my page. The issue I am coming across is that when I use `.load()`, it does not grab any javascript, so the images I grab are not in the right organization.

Here is the function I use to grab the content:

```
function loader(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#posts').fadeOut('normal',function(){$('#posts').html(data);});
        $('#posts').fadeIn('normal');
    }).error(function(url) {
        alert('error');
    });
};
```

After researching, it seems that in order to get the javascript I need to use Ajax

**Here is the thing:**

I have the exact same javascript code on my page that is the javascript for the other page that is not getting applied. Is there a way that I can apply this javascript on the items loaded with `.load()`?

## [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNDMc/19/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry requires that you tell it when you add or remove elements, so that it can resort itself accordingly. There are two ways of doing this:

1. Destroy the Masonry of $wall, Replace $wall's HTML, Construct Masonry on $wall
2. Use Masonry to destroy $wall's children, Use Masonry to add new children to $wall - [I had trouble implementing this, as it failed to align properly](http://jsfiddle.net/xsK8H/)

Following the first example, there are a few changes that I've made. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajjaz/3/)

Changed all instances of `id="entry"` to `class="entry"`, and `#entry` to `.entry`. An ID may only be used by one element at a time, while a class exists for this purpose.

Filtered the returned HTML to only include the children of #posts. We don't want to include the `<html>...<head>...</head><body>...`.

```
$newPosts = $(data).filter(function(){
    return this.id === 'posts';
}).children();
```

Destroyed Masonry, Updated the HTML, Reloaded Masonry

```
$wall.masonry('destroy');
$('#posts').html($newPosts);
$wall.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.entry, .entry_photo',
    isAnimated : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Masonry is taking care of the layout of the different items. But you are only calling the masonry function once on page load. To fix your problem you just need to call masonry again after the new items are loaded - so inside your AJAX Call in the function "loader" write something like you already did:

```
$wall.masonry({
   itemSelector: '#entry, #entry_photo',
   isAnimated: false
});
```

You could also improve your code, for example by using your $wall variable instead of $("#posts").

Comment: Could you show me how that is done, because I tried adding the masonry into my function, but that didn't do anything...